# How to know which condition was true in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

How can I know which condition in an if statement in JavaScript was true?

```
if(a === b || c === d){ console.log(correctValue) }
```

How can I know if it was either `a === b` or `c === d`?

Edit: I wanted to know if there was any way of doing this besides checking each condition on it's own if statement.

Comment: Wanted to know if it was possible, I know some JavaScript but the very surface, so I thought "this might exist", searched for it and found nothing, so here I am.

Comment: You could return the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
If it matters, it needs to be two different conditions.

```
if (a == b) {
  // it was a == b
  return true;
}

if (c == d) {
  // it was c == d
  return true;
}
```

Note that even so, you won't know if **both or just one** of these conditions is true.
If you want to know this as well, you'll want an additional `if`:

```
if (a == b && c == d) {
  // a == b and c == d
} else if (a == b) {
  // just a == b
} else if (c == d) {
  // just c == d
}

return (a == b || c == d);
```

Comment: If you remove the "return" from the first one you'll be able to know if both or just one are true, right?

Comment: @AdriánSalgado Not really, unless I check again for `a == b` inside `c == d`. That's why I'm using `else if`s in my second example and check for both conditions beforehand.

Comment: I mean, you could go if (a === b){ console.log("a equals b");} if(c === d){ console.log("c equals d"); } :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to know which condition was true, just test them separately:

```
if(a == b) {
    console.log("a == b");
    return true; 
} else if(c == d) {
    console.log("c == d");
    return true; 
}
```

Alternatively, you might prefer something like this:

```
var result;
if ((a == b && result = "a == b") || (c == d && result = "c == d")) {
    console.log(result);
    return true;
}
```

This code is effectively equivalent to the former, however, I wouldn't recommend using this in a production system. It's much harder to read and guess the original intent of the code—it's likely that the person reading this after you would think the `result =` was supposed to be `result ==`. Also note that because empty strings are falsy, you must ensure that the string you assign to `result` is never empty, otherwise it would never enter the `if`-block.

Comment: Any way of doing it not separately?

Comment: I thought there could be a nicer way, like if(a === b || c === d){ console.log(truthy) }, but I guess there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
if(e = (a === b) || (f= c === d)){ console.log(e, f, correctValue) }
```

Then You can check whether e or f is true, then make your changes.

I don't know about memory leak or something for this but yeah it works.

Comment: Yeah so, this was a very beginner question I made like 9 years ago. I think I believed there could be a way of accessing the correct value without having to previously assign it or check individually. I would honestly just follow Dan's response