# Know which condition returned False in IF..THEN statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

So I have a user sign up form. There are textboxes for *entering name*, *age*, *username*, *password*, *confirm password*, *security question* and *answer*. 
Before clicking the **Submit** button, I want to make sure all the boxes are filled and the password matches.

`PasswordMatch` returns whether the password matches or not as True or False

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    'check if everything is filled
    If Name_TxtBox.Text <> "" And Age_Box.Text <> "" And username_Box.Text.Length > 4 And PasswordMatch = True And Security_Ques.Text.Length > 5 And Answer_Box.Text.Length > 2 Then
        'yupp, everything fine. now continue
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, I want to know exactly which condition was False so I can react accordingly.

Is there some way to know this? Like catching an exception or something? I know it has nothing to do with this here but I just thought maybe we can catch which condition is false.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268364/how-to-know-which-condition-was-true-in-an-if-statement) answer and they recommended to use `ElseIf`. That could be a way but that would be too lengthy and take more lines of code.

Comment: Check them individually by using a single *if .. then* per test.  There is nothing wrong with "more lines of code" if "more lines of code" are required to accomplish a task.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use `AndAlso`, not `And` in logical expressions.

Comment: so there's just no way to know which condition returned False?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ONE if condition, I think you can't determine which of them is false, so create multiple if conditions.

```
If Name_TxtBox.Text = "" Then
    'Do whatever you want
    Return 'This exits the sub, so the following lines won't execute
End If

If Age_Box.Text = "" Then
    'Do whatever you want
    Return 'This exits the sub, so the following lines won't execute
End If

If Not username_Box.Text.Length > 4 Then
    'Do whatever you want
    Return 'This exits the sub, so the following lines won't execute
End If

If Not PasswordMatch Then
    'Do whatever you want
    Return 'This exits the sub, so the following lines won't execute
End If

If Not Security_Ques.Text.Length > 5 Then
    'Do whatever you want
    Return 'This exits the sub, so the following lines won't execute
End If

If Not Answer_Box.Text.Length > 2 Then
    'Do whatever you want
    Return 'This exits the sub, so the following lines won't execute
End If

'yupp, everything fine. now continue
```

Comment: this isn't exactly what I asked for but you did half of works so i'll give you 15 reps haha :D

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could do it this way.

```
If Name_TxtBox.Text <> "" Then
    If Age_Box.Text <> "" Then
    Else
       'Error: Age is empty
    End If
Else
   'Error: Name is empty
End If
```